# Повтороная работа скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

У меня есть 5 блоков с ссылками. При нажатии на ссылку, должна появляться менюха в модальном окне. В этой модалке есть еще одна ссылка, при нажатии на которую меню раскрывается как книжечка. Сделать это у меня получилось, но меню открывается только один раз и только для первой ссылки из тех 5 блоков. Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт отрабатывал на всех ссылках?
Это скрипт открывания меню

```js
var Menu = (function() {
    var $container = $( '#rm-container' ),                      
        $cover = $container.find( 'div.rm-cover' ),
        $middle = $container.find( 'div.rm-middle' ),
        $right = $container.find( 'div.rm-right' ),
        $open = $cover.find('a.rm-button-open'),
        $close = $right.find('span.rm-close'),
        $details = $container.find( 'a.rm-viewdetails' ),
        
        init = function() {
            initEvents();
        },
        initEvents = function() {
            $open.on( 'click', function( event ) {
                openMenu();
                return false;
            } );
            $close.on( 'click', function( event ) {
                closeMenu();
                return false;
            } );
            $details.on( 'click', function( event ) {
                $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' ).children( 'div.rm-modal' ).remove();
                viewDetails( $( this ) );
                return false;

            } );
        },
        openMenu = function() {
            $container.addClass( 'rm-open' );
        },
        closeMenu = function() {
            $container.removeClass( 'rm-open rm-nodelay rm-in' );
        },
        viewDetails = function( recipe ) {
            var title = recipe.text(),
                img = recipe.data( 'thumb' ),
                description = recipe.parent().next().text(),
                url = recipe.attr( 'href' );
            var h = $modal.outerHeight( true );
            $modal.css( 'margin-top', -h / 2 );

            setTimeout( function() {
                $container.addClass( 'rm-in rm-nodelay' );
                $modal.find( 'span.rm-close-modal' ).on( 'click', function() {
                    $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' );
                } );
            }, 0 );
        };
    return { init : init };
})();
```

```css
.rm-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  max-width: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1600px;
  -moz-perspective: 1600px;
  -o-perspective: 1600px;
  -ms-perspective: 1600px;
  perspective: 1600px;
 color: #2a323f;
 z-index: 1200;
}

.rm-wrapper,
.rm-wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.rm-wrapper .rm-cover {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.rm-wrapper .rm-middle {
  z-index: 50;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.rm-wrapper .rm-right {
  z-index: 60;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.rm-wrapper > div > div {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  /*box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 16px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 17px #e6b741, 
    inset 0 0 0 18px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 19px #e6b741, 
    inset 0 0 0 20px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 21px #e6b741;*/

}

.rm-container .rm-front,
.rm-container .rm-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.rm-container .rm-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.rm-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
}

.rm-middle .rm-overlay {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 64%, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(64%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 64%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 64%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 64%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 64%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
}

.rm-content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.rm-logo, 
.rm-content h2,
.rm-content h4,
a.rm-button-open{
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rm-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #323b4c url(../images/restaurant.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 3px #fff, 
    0 0 0 4px #e6b741, 
    0 0 0 5px #fff, 
    0 0 0 6px #e6b741, 
    0 0 0 7px #fff, 
    0 0 0 8px #e6b741;
}

.rm-content h2 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff, 3px 3px 0 #e6b741;
}

.rm-content h3 {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #323b4c;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-top: 4px double #323b4c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.rm-content h4 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #323b4c;
  border-bottom: 4px double #323b4c;
  
}

.rm-content h4:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

a.rm-button-open {
  color: #323b4c; 
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

a.rm-button-open:hover {
  color: #e6b741;
}

.rm-info p {
  line-height: 20px;
}

.rm-content dl{
  margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt,
.rm-content dl dd{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.rm-content dl dt {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rm-content dl dd {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 4px 5px 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

.rm-order p{
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(213, 193, 154, 0.2);
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

a.rm-viewdetails:before{
  font-family: 'entypo-selected';
  content: '\56';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3); */
}




.rm-thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 
    1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.rm-button-open:after {
  content: '\2192';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

a.rm-viewdetails {
  color: #e6b741;
  font-weight: 500;
}



a.rm-viewdetails:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.rm-close {
  background: #55b8e0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  top: -19px;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rm-close-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 21px;
  top: 21px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #2a323f;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Transitions */

.rm-wrapper,
.rm-wrapper > div {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out, height 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out, height 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out, height 0s;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out, height 0s;
}


.rm-close {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.rm-container.rm-open .rm-close {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.8s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.8s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.rm-container.rm-open .rm-wrapper > div {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.rm-container.rm-open .rm-cover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.rm-container.rm-open .rm-right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.rm-container.rm-in .rm-cover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-150deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-150deg);
  transform: rotateY(-150deg);
}

.rm-container.rm-in .rm-right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(150deg);
  transform: rotateY(150deg);
}

.rm-container.rm-in .rm-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-500px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(-500px);
  transform: translateZ(-500px);
}

.rm-container.rm-in .rm-cover, 
.rm-container.rm-in .rm-right,
.rm-container.rm-nodelay .rm-right {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.rm-container.rm-in {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

/* Fallback (similar to last media query) */

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 460px;
}
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-wrapper, 
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-wrapper > div,
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-wrapper > div > div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-wrapper > div > div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 16px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 17px #e6b741, 
    inset 0 0 0 18px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 19px #e6b741, 
    inset 0 0 0 20px #fff, 
    inset 0 0 0 21px #e6b741,
    0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-container .rm-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-overlay, 
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-middle .rm-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-right .rm-front {
  display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-button-open {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-button-open:after {
  content: '\2193';
}

.no-csstransforms3d {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -40%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .rm-container.rm-in .rm-cover,
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-container.rm-in .rm-right,
.no-csstransforms3d .rm-container.rm-in .rm-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1110px) {
  .rm-container {
    height: 800px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .rm-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 460px;
    -webkit-perspective: 0px;
    -moz-perspective: 0px;
    -o-perspective: 0px;
    -ms-perspective: 0px;
    perspective: 0px;
  }
  .rm-wrapper, 
  .rm-wrapper > div,
  .rm-wrapper > div > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .rm-wrapper > div > div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   /* box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 0 16px #fff, 
      inset 0 0 0 17px #e6b741, 
      inset 0 0 0 18px #fff, 
      inset 0 0 0 19px #e6b741, 
      inset 0 0 0 20px #fff, 
      inset 0 0 0 21px #e6b741,
      0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  }

  .rm-container .rm-back,
  .rm-container.rm-open .rm-cover,
  .rm-container.rm-open .rm-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  .rm-overlay, .rm-middle .rm-overlay {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .rm-right .rm-front,
  .rm-close {
    display: none;
  }

  .rm-button-open {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .rm-button-open:after {
    content: '\2193';
  }

  .rm-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -40%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

  .rm-container.rm-in .rm-cover,
  .rm-container.rm-in .rm-right,
  .rm-container.rm-in .rm-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        Menu.init();
    });
</script>
<div class="fade">
                <section class="main">
                    <div id="rm-container" class="rm-container">
                        <div class="rm-wrapper">
                            <div class="rm-cover">
                                <div class="rm-front">
                                    <div class="rm-content">
                                   
                                        <a href="#" class="rm-button-open">Открой меня</a>
                                    </div><!-- /rm-content -->
                                </div><!-- /rm-front -->
                                <div class="rm-back">
                                    <div class="rm-content">

                                        <h4>апр</h4>
                                       
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="liOpis"></li>
                                            <li class="liOpis"></li>
                                            <li class="liOpis"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div><!-- /rm-content -->
                                    
                                </div><!-- /rm-back -->
                            </div><!--/rm-cover -->
                            <div class="rm-middle">
                                <div class="rm-inner">
                                    <div class="rm-content">
                                        <h4>апрап</h4>
                                        <img src="static/images/Diagram.png">
                                    </div><!-- /rm-content -->
                                </div><!-- /rm-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /rm-middle -->
                            <div class="rm-right">
                                <div class="rm-front">
                                </div>
                                <div class="rm-back">
                                    <span class="rm-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</span>
                                    <div class="rm-content">
                                        <h4>Записаться</h4>
                                       <form>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Ф.И.О</label>
                                            <input  class="form-control" id="fio" placeholder="Ф.И.О">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Введите email">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Телефон</label>
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
                                          </div>
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Записаться</button>
                                        </form>
                                            <span>Осталось:&nbsp;</span><span class="afss_day_bv">0</span> д.
                                            <span class="afss_hours_bv">00</span>&nbsp;час.&nbsp;<br>
                                            <span class="afss_mins_bv">00</span>&nbsp;мин.&nbsp;
                                            <span class="afss_secs_bv">00&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;сек.
                                            <p></p>
                                    </div><!-- /rm-content -->
                                </div><!-- /rm-back -->
                            </div><!-- /rm-right -->
                        </div><!-- /rm-wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- /rm-container -->
                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: Сделайте воспроизводимый пример. Через "фрагмент кода"

Comment: @Даниил , сделал воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Илья Попков Здравствуйте! Вы видимо данный скрипт не сами писали, т.к. данная строка о многом говорит:  `var $container = $( '#rm-container' )` Данный **id** может быть только один на странице, а вы говорите, что у вас 5 блоков. **Итого:** вам нужно привести в пример полный HTML код(5 блоков). В начале стоит проверить его(отсутствие дублей **id**). Всего вам доброго!